# Diagonal translation using Object AnimatorAndorid

Tags: android-animation, android-view, android, objectanimator

I am trying to make a diagonal translation using object animator in Android. Following code makes a translation in Y Axis.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", -value);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`AnimatorSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) with two `ObjectAnimators`, one performing the Y translation (as in the example in your question), and a very similar one doing the X translation. Make sure to use the `playTogether(..)` method of the `AnimatorSet` and you can animate both X and Y at the same time!